# Get average value or first from JSON return array

Tags: javascript, json, object

I sometimes get `[22, 25]` and sometimes `[30]`.

If I do `console.log(show.episode_run_time[0]);` when it returns only one object in the array, it says `undefined`.

Ideally, when it returns a range, I want to get the average value. Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried, please post some code that would pertain to this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a generic solution that will satisfy arrays with one-to-many items (just not empty arrays):

```
arr.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0) / arr.length
```